# Can't get array of functions for some standard PHP extensions

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm trying to get an array of function names for extensions `Refletion`, `mysqlnd`, `xmlreader`, `Phar`, `pdo_mysql`, `xsl` using standard `get_extension_funcs()` but it returns `false` instead of array of names. This is strange as it returns names for any other module. For example, it works for `xmlwriter`. But it does not work for `xmlreader`.

I have PHP 8.0.2. What am I doing wrong? Sample code:

```sh
$ php -r "var_dump(get_extension_funcs('xmlreader'));"
bool(false)

$ php -r "var_dump(get_extension_funcs('xmlwriter'));"
array(42) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "xmlwriter_open_uri"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "xmlwriter_open_memory"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "xmlwriter_set_indent"
  [3]=>
  string(27) "xmlwriter_set_indent_string"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_start_comment"
  [5]=>
  string(21) "xmlwriter_end_comment"
  [6]=>
  string(25) "xmlwriter_start_attribute"
  [7]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_end_attribute"
  [8]=>
  string(25) "xmlwriter_write_attribute"
  [9]=>
  string(28) "xmlwriter_start_attribute_ns"
  [10]=>
  string(28) "xmlwriter_write_attribute_ns"
  [11]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_start_element"
  [12]=>
  string(21) "xmlwriter_end_element"
  [13]=>
  string(26) "xmlwriter_full_end_element"
  [14]=>
  string(26) "xmlwriter_start_element_ns"
  [15]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_write_element"
  [16]=>
  string(26) "xmlwriter_write_element_ns"
  [17]=>
  string(18) "xmlwriter_start_pi"
  [18]=>
  string(16) "xmlwriter_end_pi"
  [19]=>
  string(18) "xmlwriter_write_pi"
  [20]=>
  string(21) "xmlwriter_start_cdata"
  [21]=>
  string(19) "xmlwriter_end_cdata"
  [22]=>
  string(21) "xmlwriter_write_cdata"
  [23]=>
  string(14) "xmlwriter_text"
  [24]=>
  string(19) "xmlwriter_write_raw"
  [25]=>
  string(24) "xmlwriter_start_document"
  [26]=>
  string(22) "xmlwriter_end_document"
  [27]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_write_comment"
  [28]=>
  string(19) "xmlwriter_start_dtd"
  [29]=>
  string(17) "xmlwriter_end_dtd"
  [30]=>
  string(19) "xmlwriter_write_dtd"
  [31]=>
  string(27) "xmlwriter_start_dtd_element"
  [32]=>
  string(25) "xmlwriter_end_dtd_element"
  [33]=>
  string(27) "xmlwriter_write_dtd_element"
  [34]=>
  string(27) "xmlwriter_start_dtd_attlist"
  [35]=>
  string(25) "xmlwriter_end_dtd_attlist"
  [36]=>
  string(27) "xmlwriter_write_dtd_attlist"
  [37]=>
  string(26) "xmlwriter_start_dtd_entity"
  [38]=>
  string(24) "xmlwriter_end_dtd_entity"
  [39]=>
  string(26) "xmlwriter_write_dtd_entity"
  [40]=>
  string(23) "xmlwriter_output_memory"
  [41]=>
  string(15) "xmlwriter_flush"
}
```

Even if I assume that some extensions does not have any functions, there are some extensions which SHOULD have functions, eg. `mysqlnd` should have `mysqli_fetch_all()` as [noted in official docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.overview.php).

Also, I assure that all those extensions are loaded and working fine.

```sh
$ php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('mysqlnd'));"
bool(true)

$ php -r "var_dump(get_extension_funcs('mysqlnd'));"
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

`FALSE` is returned if there are no functions in that extension.

**For example;**

```
<?php 
  get_extension_funcs("xmlreader");
```

**Returns**;

> false

because that extension defines the XMLReader class but not functions.

[According JB comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-extension-funcs.php#67192)

Comment: OK, but does not explain `false` from `get_extension_funcs('mysqlnd')`. I asked about that at the end of my post.